# Convertir tipos de listas en Python

Tags: python

Mi problema es el siguiente; estoy haciendo una función que recibe como parámetros un fichero de datos (que en este caso se llama frecuencias.csv y está compuesto de números) y funcion_conversion=int. Esta función se usará para interpretar una cadena de caracteres como un valor numérico. El código que tengo hasta ahora es tal que así:

```
def lee_serie(fichero, funcion_conversion=int):
 f = open(fichero)
 datos_leidos = csv.reader(f)

 lista_datos = []
 if funcion_conversion == int:
     for dato in datos_leidos:
         lista_datos.append(int(dato))
     return lista_datos

 if funcion_conversion == float:
     for dato in datos_leidos:
         lista_datos.append(float(dato))
     return lista_datos
```

Sin embargo, recibo un error tal que:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Entonces mi idea, después de indagar un poco, fue cambiar lo siguiente:

```
lista_datos = []
lista_datos_int = []
lista_datos_float = []

if funcion_conversion == int:
    for dato in datos_leidos:
        lista_datos.append(dato)
        lista_datos_int = map(int, lista_datos)
    return list(lista_datos_int)

if funcion_conversion == float:
    for dato in datos_leidos:
        lista_datos.append(dato)
        lista_datos_float = map(float, lista_datos)
    return list(lista_datos_float)
```

Pero vuelvo a recibir:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar `csv.reader()` para leer un fichero csv, obtienes como resultado un *iterador* que te permite iterar sobre cada una de las filas del fichero. Es decir, en el bucle `for dato in datos_leidos`, la variable `dato` contiene una fila del CSV cada vez que iteras. Esta fila te la retorna en forma de lista.

Por tanto cuando, en tu primer intento, haces `int(dato)`, estás intentando convertir a entero una lista, y de ahí el error. Tendrías que, o bien hacer otro bucle que itere por cada elemento de esa lista, o bien usar `map(int, dato)`, que "mapea" la función `int` sobre cada elemento de una lista y te retorna otra lista con los resultados (los enteros ya convertidos).

Este segundo enfoque es el que pareces haber intentado en tu segundo código, pero lo has hecho mal, porque en cada iteración del bucle haces `lista_datos.append(dato)`, lo que va añadiendo cada fila (que ya era una lista) a otra lista llamada `lista_datos`, y después haces `map(int, lista_datos)`, lo que intentará "mapear" la función `int` a cada elemento de `lista_datos`, pero cada uno de estos elementos era otra lista (una fila), con lo que estás otra vez como en el primer caso.

Lo que buscas por tanto sería:

```
def lee_serie(fichero, funcion_conversion=int):
 f = open(fichero)
 datos_leidos = csv.reader(f)

 lista_datos = []
 if funcion_conversion == int:
     for dato in datos_leidos:
         lista_datos.append(list(map(int, dato)))
     return lista_datos

 if funcion_conversion == float:
     for dato in datos_leidos:
         lista_datos.append(list(map(float, dato)))
     return lista_datos
```

### Advertencias sobre lo anterior

- Has visto que he tenido que usar `list()` alrededor de `map()`. Esto es necesario en Python3, porque `map()` no retorna una lista directamente, sino un generador sobre el que se podría iterar. Al usar `list()` forzamos esa iteración y el resultado como lista.
- La `lista_datos` que retorna esta función es una lista cuyos elementos son a su vez listas, siendo cada una de ellas una fila del csv.
- La función fallará tan pronto como encuentre algo en una celda del csv que no sea convertible a entero (si se usó `int`) o real (si se usó `float`). Esto puede pasar fácilmente pues en la mayoría de los csv la primera fila contiene cabeceras con nombres de columnas, en lugar de números. Tal vez tu .csv sea sólo números, pero de todas formas ten esto en cuenta.

### Mejoras al código

- Has olvidado cerrar el fichero `f`. Es más seguro usar contextos para no olvidarlo. Un contexto es un bloque que comienza por `with open(fichero) as f:` y contiene todo el código que usa `f`. Al abandonar ese bloque el fichero se cierra automáticamente.
- Parece absurdo repetir el código que lee y convierte a `int`, *casi idéntico* cuando lees y conviertes a `float`. La repetición de código similar es lo que en informática se llama un *bad smell*, un síntoma de que podría hacerse mejor.

  De hecho en tu caso, tienes `if funcion_conversion == int` entonces aplicas `int`. Y después `if funcion_conversion == float` entonces aplicas `float`. ¿No es más directo aplicar directamente `funcion_conversion` y así no tener que usar un `if` ni repetir código similar?
- Finalmente, la construcción `list(map(...))` queda en mi opinión más legible si usas una *list comprehension* que es una especie de bucle implícito que automáticamente crea una lista. Si nunca has usado una, verás cómo te aficionas a ellas en cuanto les pilles el truco.

Un código que implementa estas mejoras sería el siguiente.

```
def lee_serie(fichero, funcion_conversion=int):
 with open(fichero) as f:
     datos_leidos = csv.reader(f)
     lista_datos = []
     for fila in datos_leidos:
         lista_datos.append([funcion_conversion(dato) for dato in fila])
     return lista_datos
```

Fíjate cuánto más corta ha quedado. Mira cómo se crea cada lista que se va añadiendo a `lista_datos`, haciendo uso de la *list comprehension*:

```
 [funcion_conversion(dato) for dato in fila]
```

En este caso se está iterando por cada elemento contenido en la lista `fila` (he decidido llamarla así para mayor claridad), y a cada uno de ellos se le aplica la función `funcion_conversion()`, que puede ser `int` o `float`, ¡o incluso cualquier otra! Al ir todo entre corchetes, el resultado será una lista con los resultados de cada conversión.